# getting valueerror too many values to unpack (expected 2) in send_mass_mail

Tags: python, django, tuples

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, send_mass_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
class SendMailViews(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        html_message = render_to_string('email/test.html')
        plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
        message1 = ("subject", plain_message, 'rahulsha24445@gmail.com', 
                   ['sharmaviraj300@gmail.com'], html_message)
        message2 = ("subject", plain_message, 'rahulsha24445@gmail.com', 
                   ['abhijeetlaal7899@gmail.com'], html_message)
        emailList = [message1, message2]
        send_mass_mail(emailList, fail_silently=False)
        return Response({"status": True})
```

I want to send HTML based email to a mass recipient in Django.

Comment: where `send_mass_mail` is defined? inside class or outside?

Comment: outside my class I edit my questions check

Comment: `emailList` should be tuple; not list.

Comment: Check example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/

Comment: I tried but got same error

Comment: Please include a full stack trace.